# Segmentation fault when pushing to stack in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, segmentation-fault

I am writing a problem to calculate smallest common multiple in assembly. GDB shows sigsegv exception at the very first line `pushl %ebp`. Can you tell me how to fix this?

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int nww(int a, int b);                               // Funkcja z asm
int main()
{
int a = 10, b = 3;

int nw= nww(a,b);
printf("NWW %d i %d  = %d ",a,b,nw);

return 0;
}
```

nww.s

```
.text       
.global nww
.type nww, @function        
nww:

pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp

movl 8(%ebp), %eax
movl 12(%ebp), %ebx 

nwd: 
movl $0, %edx     # miejsce na reszte 
divl %ebx              # podziel a przez b, reszta w d 
movl %ebx, %eax 
movl %edx, %ebx       # przygotowanie nastepnego dzielenia 
cmp $0, %edx
jnz nww

movl %eax, %edx     # NWD do dx

movl 8(%ebp), %eax                  # nowe A i B
movl 12(%ebp), %ebx 

imull %ebx, %eax 
divl %edx 

exit:

movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to do it in assembly?

Comment: Are you sure you want to jump to `nww` from `nwd` to the point *before* the stack handling?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The reason to do it in assembly is "I was told to.", it's a class excercise.  I did mean to jump to nwd, that's probably it, I'll check

Comment: @EugeneSh. You can add this as an answer and I'll accept it